# How to sort a HashMap first by value and then by key in case of duplicates?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a HashMap similar to this:

```
 HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
 map.put(3, 2);
 map.put(7, 2);
 map.put(5, 1);
 map.put(10, 4);
```

I need to sort it first by value and then by key in case multiple keys share the same value.

The result should look like this:

```
(5, 1)
(3, 2)
(7, 2)
(10, 4)
```

Any suggestion please?

I'm comparing the values first and the keys only in case of a duplicate value. So I'm using using both the keys and the values, not just the values.

Comment: You have to use a LinkedHashMap - because HashMap cannot maintain an order.

Comment: @AriSingh not quite a duplicate as there's a subtle difference with this question I believe.

Comment: @Aominè How is it different - Just because the values are duplicate ? Duplicate values do not change the answer/solution. Just the comparator has to do one more check.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve it like so with the streams API:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> resultSet = 
  map.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue()
                             .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

The [sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) intermediate operation can take a `Comparator` instance which in this case is:

```
Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue()
                                 .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
```

i.e. compare by the map values and if two given values are the same then compare by the key.

Moving on to the `collect` terminal operation:

`Map.Entry::getKey` is the `keyMapper` which is a mapping function to produce the map keys.

`Map.Entry::getValue` is the `valueMapper` which is a mapping function to produce the map values.

`(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue` is the merge function used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key.

`LinkedHashMap::new` provides a new empty Map into which the results will be inserted. We specified a `LinkedHashMap` here to maintain insertion order.

---

Note the merge function `(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue` is pointless in this case as the source of the stream (`map.entrySet()`) will never contain duplicate keys. However, we still need it otherwise we cannot specify the type of accumulator for the new values, in this case, a `LinkedHashMap` instance to maintain insertion order.

You may also want to look at the [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) method for further information on how it works.

Comment: Like the use of `Map.Entry.comparingByValue` and `Map.Entry.comparingByKey`.

Comment: 'How to sort a `HashMap`': stop right there. You can't.

Comment: @EJP yup hence the suggestion to accumulate the results of the stream pipeline into a `LinkedHashMap` instance.